# Edit and Share Angular Material Demos

Tags: angular-material, plunker, codepen

I am trying to share an idea for part of a webpage using Angular Material, but I can't. I am trying to send a sample using CodePen or Plunker, or any other similar webpage, but they don't load.

What I want to do is similar to the 'Demos' that they show on Angular Material webpage ([Link to Angular Material Demos](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)). 
It is strange that all Demos have a link to CodePen, but they don't load.
I tried the same code using Plunker, but it doesn't work either.

So my question is if there is any way to host Angular Material in one site like Pluker, CodePen or any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that one of the CDN links is broken.

I modified the Demos provided by Angular Material and changed its settings from:

```
https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.5/angular-material.js
```

to:

```
https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.4/angular-material.js
```

And it worked